# How to resolve linear least squares equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-curves

I need to calculate A and B after measuring y and x over a series of measurements.
$y = Ax + B$
I've been able to isolate the variables:
$a = \frac{(y - b)}{x}$
$b = -(\frac{ax}{y})$
But there's always one unknown left, in this situation neither a or b can be calculated with only knowing x and y.

This comes from a [calibration curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration_curve) problem.

Can someone help with the algebra to calculate either one of these?
Of course, if I can calculate one I'll be able to calculate the other.

Edit: After looking at the sources I realize this is a problem with two systems and two variables. Which I've found several video's on, but from which I cannot extract the principles I need to apply here.
$a = \frac{(y - b)}{x}$
$b = -(\frac{ax}{y})$

$ax = y - b$
$by = -ax$

These systems can be added, eliminating both `ax`.
However I don't know how to add `by` to `y - b`
$y - b + by = 0$
$b = y + by$ (by adding b)
$-y = -b + by$ (by removing y)

Or, in case this is correct, how b could be calculated from this formula.
Also, this solution looks way too simple.
From what I've found on the internet, the calculations should be really [complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8YuZJF8F_I).
The person in this video uses the following formulas to calculate a and b:
$a=\frac{n*sum(xy)-sum(x)*sum(y)}{n*sum(x^2)-sum(x)*sum(x)}$
$b=\frac{sum(x^2)*sum(y)-sum(x)*sum(xy)}{n*sum(x^2)-sum(x)*sum(x)}$
The sum thing doesn't really matter, my formula is for a single value. They will be summed and averaged later. Or would that be faulty?

Although the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Example) this guy seems to have used as a source no longer has these formulas.

Comment: what is exactly given here $$y=Ax+B$$?

Comment: Use least squares to fit $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner y and x can be measured.

Comment: @kimchilover Don't know what that is, will look into it.

Comment: See example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Example)